# Bring Crosswalk Application in foreground

Tags: android, webrtc, crosswalk-runtime

I want to build a WebRTC based VOIP application for Android with Crosswalk.

Is there a way to bring an Android Crosswalk application into foreground (even if the device is locked), after a request has been received via a Websocket connection?

I receive the websocket message, I can create the rtcPeerConnection, and I can createOffer in the background. But I only receive receive ICE candidates after the Crosswalk application is in the foreground.

Are there any plugins to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://phonertc.io/

Crosswalk helps you build Cordova apps and PhoneRTC helps you add WebRTC to your Cordova apps.

Comment: My problem is not the WebRTC part, but bringing the app in foreground when a call arrives and the device is already locked or anorher app is in the foreground.